# css- why can't I use height: 100% for a container?

Tags: html, css

In html I have a container in the body to contain every element and I want it to take up the whole height of the page.

When I make the height 100% it only sets it to the size needed to contain the elements, so I have to apply 100vh to the height for it to work. How can I make setting the height to 100% work?

Comment: doesn't work how? can you provide [mcve] and explain the expected vs actual output

Comment: by doesn't work I mean it only occupies the space it needs and not the entire height of the page.

Answer (score 4):

The `html` and `body` elements themselves don't have 100% height, so setting the height of something in them to 100% doesn't work. You need to set the `html` and `body` elements to 100% as well

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: for the container 100% means 100% of the height of its parent, but for the html element what does 100% mean?

Comment: @FNER setting the html element's height to 100% sets it to 100% of the browser window's height